# iptables -L lags on non localhost or anywhere address

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, iptables

I am trying to configure iptables for ubuntu 10.04 and I have a problem with iptables -L lagging on rows where the destination or source address is not localhost or anywhere. The following entries will cause lag on their row:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111-s 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 90 -d 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
```

while this does not:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 90 -j ACCEPT
```

I feel like this might be due to iptables checking to see if the ip is reachable. If not, what is the cause, if it is how can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to resolve addresses to hostnames. Adding `-n` will prevent this.